# Eclipse, bind my plugin action to the system save listener?

Tags: java, eclipse, events, plugins, save

I want to use tomcat application server already executing when I'm developping my webapps with eclipse. I don't know any eclipse plugin who connect to an executing application server (they execute it by themselves instead). So I started looking for how to develop a plugin. I create the action but I don't know how asking Eclipse to call my code for each save event.
Please help, thanks

Comment: What save event are you asking about?

Comment: When I save a file I want to get my plugin code executed.

Comment: In my plugin.xml I want to add something like
<extension point="...">...</extension>
to enable the execution of my code whenever the save action is called
Is this possible???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no extension point that allows you to see editor saves.

I think the best you can do is use an `IResourceChangeListener` to listen for all resource changes.

```
ResourcesPlugin.getPlugin().getWorkspace().addResourceChangeListener(listener);
```